# Kendo UI Grid excel export

Tags: javascript, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

Assuming I had a grid like [this](https://dojo.telerik.com/aCAZeqUk), When I export to excel, it fetch an ***ID*** and status display ***y/n*** only. What I want to be display is "**categoriesName**" and "**yes/no** status". Can anyone help me to achieve this?Thanks for you time.

[Demo in here](https://dojo.telerik.com/aCAZeqUk)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to call you function for exporting template based columns.

Add a **excelExport: yourFunctionName,** to your grid definition.
Here is an example of the function: https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/knowledge-base/grid-export-arbitrary-column-templates